# Is it possible to use a vector image instead of a line to trace a path in google static maps api?

Tags: google-maps

I use the normal javascript google maps with a google.maps.Polyline to show a path.  The path uses google.maps.Symbol that repeats in order to have a custom vector image along the path instead of a plain line.  This works great.

I want to do the same thing using the STATIC google maps image api, but I can't find anything in the documentation that will let me use anything other than lines.

I understand that this feature might have been left out of the api since you only have a limited number of characters in the url to generate the image.

Are there any tricks or work arounds available to have a repeating symbol along a path in a static google maps image?  Or even an alternative non-google tool that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the current google static maps api (v2).  A potential workaround is to dynamically load and take a screenshot of a browser viewing a standard google maps page.  That's obviously a lot of work and overhead compared to using the static api.  It is also probably against the terms of use for google maps.